# highcharter markdown presentation

Tags: r, highcharts, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm trying to build some Highchart (package HighCharter) in a reveal.js presentation. 
Now I'm adapting a spiderweb chart from this [page](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html).
this is my code:

````
 ```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results = 'asis', comment = NA}
library("highcharter")
library(magrittr)

gg<- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Where do you usually buy solar protection products? (%)") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Move the mouse pointer on the spiderweb chart to view the data") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Supermarket',
                      'Department Store',
                      'Pharmacy',
                      'Perfumery',
                      'Herbalist',
                      'Internet',
                      'Shop for Personal Care'
  ),
  tickmarkPlacement = 'on',
  lineWidth = 0) %>% 
hc_yAxis(gridLineInterpolation = 'polygon',
       lineWidth = 0,
       min = 0) %>% 
  hc_series(
    list(
      name = "Male (%)",
      data = c(14.3,
           9.1,
           35.8,
           26.3,
           4.9,
           4.6,
           4.1
  ),
  pointPlacement = 'on', color="#88C425"
  ),
 list(
  name = "Female (%)",
  data = c(17.0,
           7.0,
           40.2,
           28.8,
           18.3,
           2.2,
           3.6
  ),
  pointPlacement = 'on', color="#A8DBA8"
  )
  )


gg$show("inline", include_assets = TRUE)


```
````

Well,  the code works proprelly in the normal sintax, but then I include it in the RMarkdown sintax the result is an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
tentativo di applicare una non-funzione
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Hi! Why use gg$show() instead of gg? Highcharter don't have the show method! Edit: I see now I cant have the chart in a r presentation neither. I'll check

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, actually I tried with 'gg' and also without creating any objet... but these solutions don't work in a presentation. thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, Have You had a chance to see if You can put a Highchart in a presentation? It would be shame if we couldn't because they look so good. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Okey my friend! This work (In my envoirment).

result here http://jkunst.com/highcharter/presentation/

First of all you must use the next function which instead of print the htmlwidget save it in a html file and then put an iframe html tag calling this html.

```
knit_print.htmlwidget <- function(x, ..., options = NULL){

  options(pandoc.stack.size = "2048m")

  wdgtclass <- setdiff(class(x), "htmlwidget")[1]
  wdgtrndnm <- paste0(sample(letters, size = 7), collapse = "")
  wdgtfname <- sprintf("wdgt_%s_%s.html", wdgtclass, wdgtrndnm)

  htmlwidgets::saveWidget(x, file = wdgtfname, selfcontained = TRUE, background = "transparent")

  iframetxt <- sprintf("<iframe  frameBorder=\"0\" src=\"%s\" width=\"100%%\"   height=\"600\"></iframe>", wdgtfname)

  knitr::asis_output(iframetxt)
}
```

Basically implement the  partials solution metioned here https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/429 and here https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/414

Comment: I was searchin and it seem this was implemented on htmlwidgets https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/pull/154

Comment: Hi @jbkunst.... it works! many thanks. By the way... do you think is possible to put the chart  surce files in a folder "surce"? just to avoid people opening all the files before finding the presentation one? and another question: Very beautifull the US map! do you think is possible to do the same with italian region and provinces and region of the other european country?

Comment: Hi @Giorjet, its possible, 1) just  write the html in that place and then  modify the iframe string to look in the right place 2) Obiously its possible you just need to write a similar code like this http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highmaps.html using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/ITA.geo.json

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, 1) ok done (I'm not sure ... are the charts less responsive if are in a different folder?... maybe is just an impression). 2) emmm.. I think my expertise in programming is insufficient... Could You give me a little example of matching the code about italy (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/ITA.geo.json) and the code for Highmaps (http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highmaps.html)? thank you in advance

Comment: @Giorjet 1) no way, did you compare the two results side by side? 2) okey, is not that complex, you need to understand what the code does http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/Highcharter-Italy-Map

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, 1) I tried another time and there wasn't any difference. maybe the first time there were too many softwares open on my machine. 2) thank so much, I'm going to try the code. You are great!

Comment: Hi my friend @jbkunst. I tried the Highstock Time Series here http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highstock.html and I found them very elegant. Just a problem: It's quite difficult read the writings in gray. Do You think It's possible to make them white?

Comment: It's possible. This is a highchart topic than highcharter. First, you need to know what characteristic you want to chage  style and then search inhttp://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes or  Stackvoerflow how to do it ;). then use the `hc_theme` function to modify the style of the characteristic.

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, thank you for the advise. In fact I simply solved changing the theme. bye

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, now I have another question for you: I'm trying to use the Highstock with data that have just 1 value for month and the result is: Error: is.xts(x = x) is not TRUE. Is it necessary to have data for every days of the year?

Comment: Well...maybe  the problem is: how to create a xts object from a dataframe or raw data. I look around but explanations are not so clear for me. someone could help?....

Comment: well I found:       time <- as.POSIXct(agri.df$Col1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
library(xts)
agri.xt <- xts(x = agri.df$AGRI, order.by = time)

Comment: Hi, @jbkunst, It's me again... two questions: 1) If I make a paper for a company (using Highcharter), have I to pay the licence for Highchart? 2) highcharter is able to make maps like these ? http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown/sand-signika http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info/sand-signika . thank you

Comment: Hi @Giorjet not sure. Check http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts. No much detail in that page so I recommend send an email to be sure ;)! Tell me if you have success

Comment: @Giorjet 2) I think it is possible but is not and easy one. If I have some time I'll try to do replicate.

Comment: ok @jbkunst, Thank you. If they'll respond I'll tell you. bye